# I am trying to call another function but the control goes back to draw() very quickly

Tags: java, processing

Here is a brief idea of my code:

```
void setup() {...}

void draw() {

//Two images horizontal to each other blink alternately. //After 4 blinks function vertical_blink() is called

}

void vertical_blink() { //Two images blink vertically

}
```

The problem is that the vertical images never blink. The program goes back to the horizontal blinking. How do I get the program to stay in vertical blinking? I tried delay, while and for. All these 3 mess up the timing. Code is down here.

```
PImage water;
PImage waterh;
PImage home;
PImage homeh;

int t;
int flag = 0;

void setup() {
    size(1800, 1128);
    background(0);
    home = loadImage("C:\\IoT\\SWSG\\FinalStages\\ProcessingPics\\home.jpg");
    homeh = loadImage("C:\\IoT\\SWSG\\FinalStages\\ProcessingPics\\homeh.jpg");
    water = loadImage("C:\\IoT\\SWSG\\FinalStages\\ProcessingPics\\water.jpg");
    waterh = loadImage("C:\\IoT\\SWSG\\FinalStages\\ProcessingPics\\waterh.jpg");
    t = millis() / 1000;
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    image(home, 100, 25, 200, 200);
    image(water, 350, 25, 200, 200);
    if ((millis() / 1000) - t >= 3) {
        flag++;
        t = millis() / 1000;
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        image(homeh, 100, 25, 200, 200);
    if (flag == 1)
        image(waterh, 350, 25, 200, 200);
    if (flag == 2)
        new_section();
}

void new_section() {
    background(255);
    int t2 = millis() / 1000, flag2 = 0;
    image(home, 100, 25, 200, 200);
    image(water, 100, 250, 200, 200);
    if (millis() / 1000 - t2 >= 3) {
        flag2++;
        t2 = millis() / 1000;
    }
    if (flag2 == 0)
        image(homeh, 100, 25, 200, 200);
    if (flag2 == 1)
        image(waterh, 100, 250, 200, 200);
    if (flag2 == 2)
        flag2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: `JavaScript != Java`

Comment: This will be easier for us to help you debug if you post a [mcve] that uses simple colored rectangles instead of images.

Comment: Also, I'm really not sure what your goal is. Can you be more specific about what this program does, and how that's different from what you expected it to do? Do you have any mockups that demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`frameCount`](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html) instead of `millis()`? So your counter might like something like this

```
void draw() {

     if (frameCount % 4 == 0) {
         // Called every 4 frames
     }

     if (frameCount % 4 == 2) {
         // Called every 4 frames, but 2 frames offset
     }

}
```